# How to drop a SQL Server user with db owner privilege

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-manager

I need to drop a user with `dbowner` schema from a SQL Server database. I cannot drop it as it is since I get this error message

> Drop failed for User 'network service'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15138)

When I try to uncheck the schema owned by this user to remove the DB owner it does nothing. My question is how I can drop this user or edit its name from `'network service' to 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'`

Answer (score 49):

I had the same problem, I run two scripts then my problem is solved.

Try this:

In this query you can get user schema as a result for `AdventureWorks` database:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
SELECT s.name
FROM sys.schemas s
WHERE s.principal_id = USER_ID('your username');
```

after take schema name you can alter authorization on schema like this:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_owner TO dbo;
```

in this query `db_owner`  schema name that get from first query.

finally you can delete user without error.

my source: [SQL SERVER – Fix: Error: 15138](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/12/26/sql-server-fix-error-15138-the-database-principal-owns-a-schema-in-the-database-and-cannot-be-dropped/)

Comment: This option worked for me after trying the accepted answer first (which did not help; not sure why, they are very similar).

Comment: This solution is work for me. Other solution to change owner - not work, user is steal launch error when I want to delete it.

Answer (score 21):

I have the same issue, I cannot delete the user

> foo

since it says:

[image]

So I need to go to Security -> Schemas and look for dbo, then right click and choose Properties:

[image]

Then change

> foo

to

> dbo

then after that I can now delete the user that I want to delete.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In my case I execute these commands and problem solved:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_owner TO dbo;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_datareader TO dbo;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_datawriter TO dbo;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM] TO dbo
```